# FRAM : excessive erase of one memory cell can damage another memory cell?

Tags: non-volatile-memory, flash-memories

Erroneously , we made excessive erase of FRAM first 1024 bytes multiple times (millions and more erases).

Afterwards we observed that memory upper half is damaged (part of it).

Can it be that excessive erase of one memory cell damage another memory cell ?

Comment: One wouldn't think so.  FRAM can be good for trillions of writes. If you wrote a cell 1000 times / second x 60 seconds / minutes x 60 minutes / hour, that would only be  3.6 million writes.  Then writing 1K of bytes would take even longer.  Are you sure something else isn't correct?

Comment: We might made trilion on writing. Let's assume we got to trillions. The actual question is if exceeding the limit on some cells will damage others ?

Comment: I don't know.   You'd have to check in with the manufacturer.